# Access violation reading location - non-terminated string (unreadable memory)

Tags: c++, logging, visual-studio-2012, access-violation, log4cplus

I'm using log4cplus library and I can't get logging to work.

I use this code:

```
PropertyConfigurator::doConfigure(LOG4CPLUS_TEXT("log.properties"));
Logger g_logger = Logger::getInstance(LOG4CPLUS_TEXT("mylogger"));

LOG4CPLUS_WARN(g_logger, LOG4CPLUS_TEXT("test test test"));
```

And it breaks at `LOG4CPLUS_WARN` with error:
`Access violation reading location`

This is my Call Stack:

```
msvcp110d.dll!std::basic_streambuf<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t> >::egptr() Line 236    C++
ProjectClientd.exe!std::basic_stringbuf<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t> >::str() Line 103 C++
ProjectClientd.exe!std::basic_ostringstream<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t> >::str() Line 553 C++
>   ProjectClientd.exe!wWinMain(HINSTANCE__ * hInstance, HINSTANCE__ * hPrevInstance, wchar_t * lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) Line 55    C++
ProjectClientd.exe!__tmainCRTStartup() Line 528 C
ProjectClientd.exe!wWinMainCRTStartup() Line 377    C
```

where `wWinMain ... line 55` is a place where `LOG4CPLUS_WARN` is being called.

I have checked what's wrong with this `basic_ostringstream` and it seems that something is messed up with encoding or something:
[image]

Non-terminated string (unreadable memory) and a whole bunch of strange letters at the end of my string? What may cause it?

Comment: I don't know log4cplus but it seems to be a wide char/narrow char confusion. Notice your stack trace says `basic_stringbuf<wchar_t` (wide chars) but your code supplies narrow chars `"test test test"`. As an experiment try `LOG4CPLUS_WARN(g_logger, _T("test test test"));`

Comment: @john Look at the expanded `_Stringbuffer` view, it is a wide character string all right (`L"test test test..."`).

Comment: @john I've tried with `_T`, same result unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Have you solved your problem? I have the same error, and I've noticed, that I linked with release version of log4cplusU.dll while application was built in debug, so linkage with log4cplusUD.dll for debug configuration solved my issue

Comment: Unfortunaltey I haven't yet solved my problem. I finally used GLOG library instead of log4cplus. Anyway, I've already checked the solution you gave, I think I found it somewhere else also. But I was using the right dlls, so that was not a reason in my case.